# iOS 5 Screen size without using default-568@2x.png

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa

I am using iOS 6, and have set the deployment target as 5.0. But Appstore does not allow default-568@2x.png with iOS version lower than 6. Is there any way to handle the screen size of 4 inch screen without using default image?

Comment: Are you using the iOS 6 SDK, because vor the 4" screen screen size you will need to use the iOS 6 SDK. There should be no problem setting the deployment target to 5 with the `Default-568@2x.png` in de the app.

Answer (score 3):

To be able to start with the 4inch size on the iPhone 5 you have to add a Default-568@2x.png splash screen and compile with the iOS 6 SDK.

Of course you can still use you deployment target to 5.0+ while you are building your app with the iOS 6 SDK as base SDK (the deployment target and the base SDK are 2 different things, with the iOS 6 SDK you can target iOS 4.3+)

If you add a iPhone 5 splash screen and you're using the iOS 5 SDK as base SDK, you app will be rejected.

A short tips: try to create a new project with the latest Xcode version and you will find a basic Default-568@2x.png black splash screen which will allow you to start on the iPhone 5 screen size without artwork.